# Reclaim an app by app_id

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I have an app that was linked with my facebook account. I deactivated my account for a a few days and when I came back I can't find my apps in the apps section. I do have a likebox on my website which links to a page I created for the app. It is through that likebox that I got the appID. 
Is there any way to get the app connected to my account back again with the appID that I have?